# XSLT Whitelist with XPATH

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xml-parsing

I would like to create the XSLT 1.0 transformation for whitelisting XML elements with XPATH.

My XML looks like this:

```
<ns:stuff>
 <ns:things>
  <ns:currency>somecurrency</ns:currency>
  <ns:currency_code/>
  <ns:currency_code2/>
  <ns:currency_code3/>
  <ns:currency_code4/>
 </ns:things>
</ns:stuff>
```

My XSLT I'm developing and does not work for xpath but it works for elemenet names (I need xpath):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:ns="some:ns">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <ns:WhiteList>
  <name>//stuff/things/currency</name>
  <name>//stuff/things/currency_code3</name>
 </ns:WhiteList>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match=
  "*[not(descendant-or-self::*[name()=document('')/*/ns:WhiteList/*])]"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I'd like to get:

```
<ns:stuff>
 <ns:things>
  <ns:currency>somecurrency</ns:currency>
 </ns:things>
</ns:stuff>
```

Many thanks for help.

Comment: Your whitelist includes `//stuff/things/currency_code3`; why is this not in your desired output?

Comment: This is far from trivial to accomplish in XSLT 1.0. See something quite similar here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21632622. -- Note that your input elements have a namespace prefix, but your paths do not. That  makes it even more complicated; you certainly cannot use `name()` to generate a path without prefixes - and if you remove them, you run the danger of false positive matches.